# Google Analytics to Bigquery Two Views to same project

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, universal-analytics

I am trying to setup a Google Analytics to Bigquery export. I want to export two separate property views to the same bigquery project. After setting up the export I saw that only one of the property views was exported to bigquery. For the other one even though a dataset was created it was empty. Can someone please tell me if it is possible to link to two separate GA views to the same bigquery project?

Regards,

Sriram

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to link two views to BigQuery. Also if you unlink one view and link the other, historic data for that other view will not be backfilled to BigQuery - the backfill happens only once on the initial link.

Our workaround for that has been to always link an unfiltered view, and recreate the effects of view filters via our SQL queries.